# creating a 'total' row AND column to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

|  | Government | Non Government |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boy | 240 | 423 |
| Girl | 142 | 400 |

and I need to get something like this:

|  | Government | Non Government | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy | 240 | 423 | 663 |
| Girl | 142 | 400 | 542 |
| TOTAL | 382 | 823 | 1205 |

The problem is that the teacher told that we can't use any additional packages. So far I discovered how to add the 'total' column OR row using 'row and colSums', something like this:

```
df1 = read.csv("/home/schumacher/Downloads/students_adaptability_level_online_education.csv", TRUE, ',')
df2 <- xtabs(~ Gender + Institution.Type, data=df1)
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(df2)
df2$TOTAL <- rowSums(df2)
```

When I try to add "colSums(df2)" I get this error:
`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, TOTAL, value = c(Government = 382,  :  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2`

Comment: `addmargins(xtabs(~ Gender + Institution.Type, data=df1), 1:2, list(TOTAL = sum))`

Answer (score 1):

I totally disagree with your teacher. Especially if they are trying to get you to code at the imperative level with R. R to my mind is best thought of in functional and object-oriented ways ways and to get intro students OUT of the imperative mindset. This is part of the basis of the old "no for-loops in R" advice. You CAN go that route, it's just not efficient, modern R.

That said, with base R, there are plenty of functions. Your problem breaks down into 3 parts a) new col of row sums, b) new row of col sums, and c) the grand total cell.

```
df <- data.frame(gov = c(100, 200), nongov = c(150,50))
rownames(df) <- c("boy","girl")
df$rsums <- rowSums(df) # declares col of row sums
df[3,] <- colSums(df) # declares row of col sums & completes b) and c)
```